# Is it possible in SourceTree commit only one "hunk" of changes?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible in sourcetree commit only one "hunk" of changes? As I see I can dismiss a "hunk" of changes, but I can not commit them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can selectively stage blocks (also known as "hunks") of code to be committed using git and SourceTree. Here is an example:

[image]

In the image above, I have selected to view changes in my working copy. 2 hunks are displayed. In the first hunk, I selected 2 specific lines, which I can then selectively stage to be committed. Note that you can only stage ***consecutive*** lines at a time with this method, so if you want to selectively stage non-consecutive lines, you have to select them 1 at a time.

For the 2nd hunk, instead of staging individual lines, I can instead choose to stage the entire hunk.

After you're done staging the lines or hunks of code that you want, anything remaining unstaged changes will remain in your working copy, but won't be committed until you stage them too. It is in this way that you can selectively pick lines or hunks of code to be committed from your modified working copy.

Comment: Thank you for causing me to see the Selected Lines buttons, to which I was formerly unaccountably blind.

Comment: Note, in Windows Sourcetree as of version 1.6.14.0, the extra buttons to select lines do not appear. (reproduced on win7 and server 2012)

Comment: There's only "Discard lines"/"Discard hunk" buttons in SourceTree 2.0.5.2 on OS X. Does anyone have any idea if the stages buttons are gone?

Comment: The button was missing in a few versions: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/10406393

Comment: For git these buttons are there. Sadly, for mercurial they aren't there yet.

Comment: Note, in Windows the buttons ***only appear once you select lines***, and they ***replace*** the hunk buttons.